# Sublime Text 2 Code Formatting

Tags: sublimetext, prettify, sublimetext2

First let me say I come from a Microsoft background and Visual Studio is my bread and butter.  It has a command (keybind is arbitrary) that auto-formats *any* code syntax.  The same command works in HTML, CSS, Javascript, C#, etc.

I have tried plugins for ST2 and so far I've found most don't work on a Windows box and if they do, it's for a very specific purpose like just Javascript.

I have tried (and opened Issues where appropriate):

https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify

https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat  (this one actually works)

https://github.com/welovewordpress/SublimeHtmlTidy

Have any Windows users of ST2 found anything that works to format CSS/HTML/Javascript, preferably in one shot?

**Edit:** Since this question is getting lots of views with no activity, I'll say that I *am* still looking for a plugin that can format various script types within the same command.

**October 2013**
Still haven't found anything that covers JS+CSS+HTML well however I have settled on [JsFormat](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) as by far the most effective and bug free with the least amount of configuration for just JavaScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't speak for the 2nd or 3rd, but if you install Node first, Sublime-HTMLPrettify works pretty well.  You have to setup your own key shortcut once it is installed.  One thing I noticed on Windows, you may need to edit your path for Node in the %PATH% variable if it is already long (I think the limit is 1024 for the %PATH% variable, and anything after that is ignored.)

There is a Windows bug, but in the issues there is a fix for it. You'll need to edit the HTMLPrettify.py file - https://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify/issues/12

Comment: I was actually involved in the discussion in one of those open issues (that is still open).  I'll check out the potential solution you linked and get back to you

Comment: finding something for PHP in one shot is really difficult and annoying. the tool is great but a simple formatter is hard to find. Thes php_beautifier for Sublime is exhausting. The main issue in all formatters is that you have to tweek one or two things before using them.

Comment: @JuniorMayhé did you find anything for PHP? I'm really into Aptana's CTRL+SHIF+F, which formats ANYTHING (say HTML, JS, PHP, Ruby and Python!!!)

Comment: @Leonel, Aptana is for Linux right? I am using Sublime on Windows. The prettify was not working fine for me and I uninstalled it.

Comment: @JuniorMayhé no, it's cross-platform and actually I'm using it on Windows!

Answer (score 112):

A similar option in Sublime Text is the built in `Edit->Line->Reindent`. You can put this code in `Preferences -> Key Bindings User`:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent"}
```

I use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> because I'm a Netbeans user.

To format your code, select all by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and "your key combination". Excuse me for my bad english.

---

Or if you don't want to select all before formatting, add an argument to the command instead:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }
```

(as per comment by [@Supr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171043) below)

Comment: If you find it annoying to select everything (sort of breaks the editing flow), then you can add an argument to the command instead: `{ "keys": ["alt+shift+f"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} }` ([source](http://nicksantan.com/blog/2012/12/adding-auto-format-code-indenting-to-sublime-text-2/))

Answer (score 13):

[Sublime CodeFormatter](https://github.com/akalongman/sublimetext-codeformatter) has formatting support for PHP, JavaScript/JSON/JSONP, HTML, CSS, Python. Although I haven't used CodeFormatter for very long, I have been impressed with it's JS, HTML, and CSS "beautifying" capabilities. I haven't tried using it with PHP (I don't do any PHP development) or Python (which I have no experience with) but both languages have many options in the `.sublime-settings` file.

One note however, the settings aren't very easy to find. On Windows you will need to go to your `%AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text #\Packages\CodeFormatter\CodeFormatter.sublime-settings`. As I don't have a Mac I'm not sure where the settings file is on OS X.

As for a shortcut key, I added this key binding to my "`Key Bindings - User`" file:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+d"],
    "command": "code_formatter"
}
```

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> because that's what Visual Studio uses for formatting. You can change it, of course, just remember that what you choose might conflict with some other feature's keyboard shortcut.

**Update:**

It seems as if the developers of Sublime Text CodeFormatter have made it easier to access the `.sublime-settings` file. If you install CodeFormatter with the Package Control plugin, you can access the settings via the `Preferences -> Package Settings -> CodeFormatter -> Settings - Default` and override those settings using the `Preferences -> Package Settings -> CodeFormatter -> Settings - User` menu item.

Comment: except that CodeFormatter is broken and some blocks of text it will keep adding extra indents to every time you run it. Which makes it unusable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is not quite what you're looking for, but it will fomat any language with the same keyboard shortcut.
The solution are [language specific keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38791826/sublime-text-3-language-specific-goto-definition-keyboard-shortcut).

For every language you want to format, you must find and download a plugin for that, for example a html formatter and a C# formatter. And then you map the command for every plugin to the same key, but with a differnt context (see the link).

Greets