# How to split a single line CSS file for readability?

Tags: css, text-editor

This is hardly a programming question but I am dealing with a 3rd party CSS file that I would like to examine but it is all one line.  I tried both the `Sublime 2` text editor and `Eclipse CSS editor` but neither would split the file contents into style blocks easily consumable by the naked eye.

What are some tools that can split a single line CSS file into multi line style blocks for readability?

Comment: http://www.codebeautifier.com/ Or just google `css foramtter`

Answer (score 5):

Download and install the code editor Brackets. (It's free)
http://brackets.io/

Once installed, open it and go to File->Extension Manger.
Search for and install "Beautify".

Once the extension is installed, close and re-open Brackets.

Now open the minified css file in Brackets and go to Edit->Beautify or press Cmd-Shift-L(Mac) / Ctrl-Shift-L(Win) key.

The css file should now be beautified and easy to read.

Comment: Agreed, Brackets is a great text editor.

Comment: So is [Atom](http://www.atom.io)

Comment: Didn't work for me - just left the single line css as a block

Answer (score 3):

I have found "HTML, CSS & JavaScript Minifier/Maxifier" as a very useful on-line tool to split minified CSS contents into style blocks. Here is the link to the site.

```
<http://codepen.io/depthdev/pen/HKuLs>
```

The same tool could be used to split minified JavaScript and HTML files. And it could be used to minify HTML, CSS and JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different code "beautifiers" This SO question ([Sublime Text 2 Code Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014165/sublime-text-2-code-formatting)) and subsequent answers should give you a good start.

Many people who saw that post found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14450471/2319844) to be helpful. Basically what [Sergio Morlán](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1998836/sergio-morl%c3%a1n) said is that there is a built in option in Sublime Text that can be found in 
`Edit->Line->Reindent`.

Other answers to the question include using [HTML Prettify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10299234/2319844), and [Sublime CodeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16216013/2319844).

Answer (score 0):

**SynWrite** editor (free, Windows). Go to Options/AddonsManager/Install, type "css format" and install item "CSS format".

After opening css file, call menuitem "Plugins/ CSS Format".