# Sublime Text 3 - Language specific Goto definition Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: python, go, sublimetext3

How can I set "Goto Definition" work according to the language I'm working on.

For example:

In Python I want to use PythonIDE's go to definition:

```
{
        "keys": ["ctrl+d"],
        "command": "python_goto_definition"
    },
```

And, for any other language, for instance Go, I want to use GoSublime's go to definition:

```
{
        "keys": ["ctrl+d"],
        "command": "go_sublime_goto_definition"
    },
```

I'm wondering how can I set the context?

Comment: Why aren't you using language-specific plugins that will handle that for you? GoSublime for example.

Comment: That works but not according to my requirement. In that case I need to define a shortcut for every language's goto definition function.

Comment: A shortcut definition for specific file type(json) example is https://stackoverflow.com/a/73857676/1020512 . This is working for me, and i hope a modified version of this will work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context that you want is for `selector`:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+d"],
    "command": "python_goto_definition",
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.python" }
    ]
},
```

You can add more or less specificity as needed. Use <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+P</kbd> or <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+P</kbd> (MacOS) to view the scope selector for the current position.

Comment: And, what if we want to do the same for Ctrl+click shortcuts?

Comment: I don't think there is an analog for setting such a context in a `sublime-mousemap` file, although I could be wrong. Documentation on it seems sparse and I wasn't able to find any examples that do it. It might be possible via a custom plugin command that would examine the filename/syntax of the clicked in view and then run the appropriate command, though.