# Set a Sublime Text 3 key binding conditionally based on file type

Tags: sublimetext3

I'd like to use the same key mapping to run different commands depending on the type of file currently being edited in Sublime Text 3.  What `context` do I use in `.sublime-keymap` to control this?

For example:

```
{
   "keys": ["super+shift+h"],
   "context": ?????, // --> want this for .vue files
   "command": "htmlprettify"
},
{
   "keys": ["super+shift+h"],
   "context": ?????, // --> want this for all other files
   "command": "js_prettier"
}
```

...or is there a better/easier way to do this than with contexts?

(I can do this, which would run *both* commands, but I need it to be one or the other.)

```
{
    "keys": ["super+shift+h"],
    "commands": [
        {"command": "htmlprettify"}, {"command": "js_prettier"}
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to use `context` for this. It's also possible to define your own custom command that detects the kind of file that you're editing and does something different, but that's still going to rely on the same mechanisms for checking and is more involved, so it's easier and the intention is clearer to just do it directly in the key binding.

The context that you want for this would use the `selector` key to check that the scope at the current cursor location is something specific to the type of file that you're currently editing.

For example, I have this key binding in my custom key bindings so that the key for wrapping text always wraps at 79 columns while editing `Markdown` files, even though I have the ruler set to 80 columns.

```json
{
    "keys": ["alt+q"], 
    "command": "wrap_lines", 
    "args": {"width": 79}, 
    "context": [
        { 
            "key": "selector", 
            "operator": "equal", 
            "operand": "text.html.markdown"
        }
    ]
},
```

In order to know what scope to put in the `operand` part of this, you can use the `Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name` command from the menu (or the associated key binding, which you can see by checking the menu) while the cursor is at the location you want the key bind to work.

Depending on the location of the cursor in the file, the scope will be more specific to the particular location in the file, and the more of the scope that you use, the more specific the key binding is.

For example, the scope here is `text.html.markdown`; if I used just `text`, it would work in all text files (plain text, any HTML file, etc), while using `text.html` would constrain it only to HTML files and markdown files.

For the case of wanting the command to work in all other kinds of files, you don't need to use any context at all. Without a context, the key binding is just globally always available unless another binding with a context is more specific to the current situation

That's why in the case above I can just bind the <kbd>Alt+Q</kbd> key to this command and have it work differently in `Markdown` files, but in all other cases it would just do what it normally does.

---

[edit]

As you mentioned in your comment below, I forgot to mention that the order of the key bindings is relevant, although this is not always entirely apparent (as in my example above).

Per the [Unofficial Documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/index.html) on [Key Bindings](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#order-of-preference-for-key-bindings):

> Key bindings in a keymap file are evaluated from the bottom to the top. The first matching context wins.

As such, if you're going to have multiple binds of the same key, you need to put the most generic one first in the file and the most specific one last, so that as Sublime traverses the list of matching bindings, it hits the generic one only when nothing more specific applies.

As a contrived example, the following set of key bindings makes the <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> key insert different text in a `Lua` source file than in all other files. If the order is reversed, the global key is found first (and always matches):

```json
{
    "keys": ["alt+f1"], "command": "insert", "args": {
        "characters": "The Global Key Binding"
    }
},

{
    "keys": ["alt+f1"], "command": "insert", "args": {
        "characters": "The Lua Key Binding"
    },
    "context": [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.lua" },
    ],
},
```

Note also that many resources in Sublime (`sublime-keymap` included) can be specified in more than one package, which causes Sublime to combine all of the similarly named files together.

This happens [in a specific order](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#merging-and-order-of-precedence), roughly summarized as `Default` first, `User` last, and everything else in between (see the link for the complete details).

Your custom key bindings are always going to be in the `User` package and thus loaded last, which means that you can probably always safely override anything and have the order be what you expect.

There may be some cases where you have a package installed whose default binding for a key contains a context, and you want to re-use that key in a more global way while not interfering with the package key binding.

In those sorts of cases, you would need to copy the default binding to your own user key bindings along with making your custom binding, so that you can ensure that the ordering is still correct.

This is probably a very rare case, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This got me 90% of the way there, the detail on how to find the current scope was especially helpful. One extra kink I had to work out, and that you may want to incorporate into this answer, was that the order of the defined key bindings is apparently significant: the more specific rule with context "text.html.vue" had to follow the generic rule -- putting them the other way around caused the generic rule to run in all contexts.

Comment: Answer updated, sorry about forgetting about that part initially. Glad you got everything all working regardless though. :)

Comment: how to bind only if type of file is "php" for exemple ?

Comment: @Matrix you'd get the PHP scope using Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name and use that value as the `operand` in the `context`.

Comment: thx, that works :) `embedding.php` here

Answer (score 2):

i did try to do this in Sublime Text 4, and using *Tools -> Developer -> Show Scope Name* made my day. Here is how i did it in *Preferences -> Key Bindings* (using [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON)'s reindenting on json files )

```
{ "keys": ["shift+alt+f"], "command": "pretty_json", "context": [
    { 
        "key": "selector", 
        "operator": "equal", 
        "operand": "source.json"
    }
]
}
```